# MYSQL SELECT with LIMIT from multiple Databases and Order By

Tags: mysql

I have an application that uses multiple MYSQL Databases and result is merged into one, but there is an issue when using to my queries LIMIT.

I have:

MYSQL 1 - view_users

MYSQL 2 - view_users

MYSQL 3 - view_users

Have query:

```
SELECT * FROM `view_users` 
ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 0, 25
```

The result that i get is correct:

MYSQL 1 - return 25 rows

MYSQL 2 - return 25 rows

MYSQL 3 - return 25 rows

The result that i want to achieve is to get just 25 rows instead of 75 rows, because my pagination broke.

**Desired result:
MYSQL 1, MYSQL 2, MYSQL 3 - return 25 rows in total**

Is that possible to achieve this on MYSQL level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the different db are on the same server  you could use union

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM db1.`view_users` 
  UNION 
  SELECT * 
  FROM db2.`view_users` 
  UNION 
  SELECT * 
  FROM db2.`view_users` 
  ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 0, 25
```

Comment: i did a try, yes it did the job, but do not know if i can fit this in my project, just question but to achieve same result by connecting on each mysql separated, is that possible?

Comment: If the db are on the same server  should be possible .. but  if the dbs  are on different server  you should use a replica  or a federate storage engine  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html

Comment: all the DBs are on same server, could u help me if can be this achieved by connecting one by one?

Comment: You don't need  a connection one by one .. but eventually a proper  grant to the (unique / first) connection db to the others ..

Comment: looks i complicate the things, the reason is when i connect one by one i know which pool is connecting so i append some specific data to each row but in that case do not know from which db data came, looks your answer did the job will see how to sort out my other side of problem. Thanks a lot

Comment: is not complicated .. just  once you are connected  to one db  .. try a query on a secondo db using the format  ` SELECT * FROM second_db_name.table_name`  and check

Comment: can u give me a draft example? from what i post i connect to 1 db and got 25 rows back,2 again 25 and third again 25, i guess here i need to check, or in code order by date and get first 25 and remove the other?

Comment: What are you using for execute you query .. PHP server side..   sql console ..sql IDE ???

Comment: Python tornado server side @scaisEdge

Comment: I'm not in python by for a db connect you should obtain a connection object (object/ handler/pointer  .. some of refer the query to a connect)   ..  then using  just one connection object  use a query as in my answer .. with  each table/vew  prefixed by the specific db name

Comment: i did that way works, just did connection to mysql server and from your example did it to work, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

As I know, Mysql don't support your requirement.

But have two solutions for this:

- 1: multi Mysql databases store data in order: so you can get you wanted sorted data.
- 2: if data stored out-of-order: you get each 25 rows from three database, then you must rank 25 * 3 = 75 rows data and get returned 25 rows data. But you need to notice, If you want get 25-50 rows data, you also must get 50 rows data from three database and rank, it's very complex.